# Get element which is scrolling

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, element

i have to find out, which element get scrolled (y-axis).

i need this for the following events:

- `$(document).bind('touchmove', function (event)`
- `$(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function (event)`

these events also be accessed while scrolling in any element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
     $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function (event){
               console.log(event.target);// or alert it like below to know the id or any
               alert(event.target.id);
     });
```